# Rename remote git branch without fetch

Tags: git, github

I've got a **orphan branch** `new-version` for a completely new version of my application.

On my local system I haven't got the `master branch`. I only have the `new-version branch by doing`git init` and that manually adding origin and pushing to a new branch.

I'd like to rename the `master` branch to `archived-v1`, so I can push the `new-version` branch as `master`.

The repository is rather large. So I want to rename the `master` branch without having to fetch / pull it first.

**How can I rename a remote branch without fetching it to my local system?**

---

There is no master on my local system, only remote. So:

```
$ git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

$ git checkout origin/master
error: pathspec 'origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: You may use "git branch -m master archived-v1" and then "git branch -m new-version master". These commands will rename your branches and later you can force push the branch to origin. Try it, if you are happy with the solution, i will post my answer too :)

Comment: I don't have the master branch locally, so `git branch -m` won't work.

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels I updated my answer without using `fetch`, you just need a single commit locally that `origin/master` has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to try and do a merge server-side (using a GitHub pull request) to preserve the commits in `origin/master`, and then move the `HEAD` of `local/master` before finally force pushing `master` up.

I would try to determine a commit that you:

1. Have locally (and)
2. Is contained in `origin/master`

```
git checkout (your determined commit)
git checkout -b archived-v1
git push origin archived-v1
```

Then open a pull request on GitHub to merge `origin/master` into `origin/archived-v1` (should be a fast-forward without conflicts).

Move the head of `origin/master`

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard new-version
git push -f origin master
```

Comment: The question is how to do it without fetching / pulling master to my local system.

Comment: I don't have a commit that is contained in origin/master. The new branch is an orphan.

Comment: Note, that the question requirements didn't change I'm just trying to make it clear, as I'm getting incorrect answers.

Comment: Maybe you could try to check out your initial local commit and push that up as your `archived-v1` branch for the pull request. The issue here is that you need to do the merge server-side but you can't afford a conflict in that case.

Comment: Ok, sounds like a plan :)